# how display page content(DOM) to the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, pry

please help solve the problem. i use rspec + capybara + pry.

test:

```
it 'check albums page' do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)  
  visit user_albums_path(user.id)      
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)      
  expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  expect(page).to have_selector(".albums_list_label")     
end
```

result:

```
Failures:
  1) AlbumsController index action check albums page
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector(".albums_list_label")
       expected to find css ".albums_list_label" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/controllers/albums_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

i need display page content (DOM) to the concole. i try use gem 'pry':

```
it 'check albums page' do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)  
  visit user_albums_path(user.id)      
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)      
  expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  binding.pry
  expect(page).to have_selector(".albums_list_label")     
end
```

in result i get debug mode in console:

```
    12:     it 'check albums page' do
    13:       user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)  
    14:       visit user_albums_path(user.id)      
    15:       expect(response.status).to eq(200)      
    16:       expect(response).to render_template(:index)
 => 17:       binding.pry
    18:       expect(page).to have_selector(".albums_list_label")     
    19:     end      
    20: 

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AlbumsController::IndexAction>)>
```

but i do not know how output DOM to console

Comment: maybe `puts page.body`

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use capybara in controller tests? It's really designed only for feature tests

Comment: Luis Menjivar, thanks. it worked